# .Net MVC: multi-page registration, how to secure sensitive input

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, registration, password-protection

I have a .net mvc application where users can register. The registration consists of 2 pages, and on the first page users can select a password. They are then redirected to another page to complete the registration. I store the password in a hidden field in the second view (which comes back from controller), but do not feel comfortable with that. What is best practices here, can you help me? Should I avoid using multiple views at all?

Comment: Can you have two div on submit of first form and then hide first div and show another div?

Comment: yes if this is the best solution?

Comment: I would suggest changing the workflow to ask for password (and any other sensitive info) last in the process.

Comment: Can you offload identity to 3rd party using something like Auth0 or do the requirements dictate storing logins?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of below solution:

```
1.) Implement your own Encrypt, Decrypt logic.
2.) Encrypt the password when you receive in controller.
3.) Return the encrypted password in controller to View.
4.) Store the encrypted password in hidden field
5.) Decrypt the password again at server side whenever you require.
```